# Corda - How do you implement expectEvents parallel predicates using Java

Tags: corda

I'm looking for a Java example similar to the Kotlin code shown in the following example (taken from the Corda integration testing tutorial at: https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-M6.0/tutorial-integration-testing.html)

```
bobVaultUpdates.expectEvents {
     parallel(
         (1 .. 10).map { i ->
             expect(
                 match = { update: Vault.Update ->
                                    (update.produced.first().state.data as Cash.State).amount.quantity == i * 100L
                 }
             ) { update ->
                 println("Bob vault update of $update")
             }
         }
     )
}
```

I'm also curious if this technique is still recommended, as it seems to have been removed from the latest version of this tutorial (https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V4.3/tutorial-integration-testing.html).

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to is broken, however, there is a Corda 4.4 version of the tutorial.

here's the link :

https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-integration-testing.html

There is some similar java code to what you shared here but the examples have been changed a bit.

```
Class<Vault.Update<Cash.State>> cashVaultUpdateClass = (Class<Vault.Update<Cash.State>>)(Class<?>)Vault.Update.class;

expectEvents(bobVaultUpdates, true, () ->
        expect(cashVaultUpdateClass, update -> true, update -> {
            System.out.println("Bob got vault update of " + update);
            Amount<Issued<Currency>> amount = update.getProduced().iterator().next().getState().getData().getAmount();
            assertEquals(DOLLARS(1000), Structures.withoutIssuer(amount));
            return null;
        })
);
```

Thanks!